# Cannot find device "can0" with Ubuntu-Server 20.04

Tags: can

my question is about using the SPI interface to do some things with CAN.
On my Raspberry with the Raspberry OS everything worked fine.

Since I want to use the CAN data with ROS, I decided to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on it.
In doing so, I ran into a problem (Cannot find device "can").

These are my configurations:

```
$ nano /boot/config.txt 

dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can1,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835
dtparam=spi=on
```

.

```
$ ./can_setup.sh 
#!/bin/bash

ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000
ip link set can1 up type can bitrate 1000000
```

.

```
$ ls /dev/
```

shows me that spidev0.0 and spidev0.1 are present

I have analyzed MISO MOSI and SCK with a logic analyzer and seen nothing.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

assuming, that you use Ubuntu as OS for running ROS, you should make your entries for dtoverlay inside the /etc/firmware/config.txt.

My can bus device with MCP2515 works fine with Ubuntu 22.04.

Then try

```
ls /sys/bus/spi/devices/spi0.0/net
```

It should show something like

```
can0
```

Hope this helps ...